# sdkmanager / flutter on arch unable to run

Tags: java, android, flutter, arch

## Goal

I'm currently trying to install Flutter on Arch.

I have decided to go the easy route and just install Android Studio for the SDK and other related software.

I have `flutter doctor`

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on Arch Linux 6.1.45-1-lts, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for more details.
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

## Problem

`flutter doctor --android-licenses`.

Whenever I run it, I recieve;

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found
Android sdkmanager tool was found, but failed to run (/home/ryann62/Android/Sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager): "exited code 1".
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

Additionally, trying `./sdkmanager --list` either gives me;

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found
```

with java-17-openjdk
or

```
Error: Could not find or load main class java.se.ee
```

with java-8-openjdk

Also, i'm using Flutter v3.10, and Android-Studio Giraffe.

## What have I tried?

I have tried reinstalling Android-Studio, 
I have tried reinstalling my Android SDK  
I have tried setting and unsetting JAVA_OPTS to JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee' 
I have tried java-8-openjdk, java-17-openjdk, java-20-openjdk, ensuring I only have one version installed at a time and setting JAVA_HOME correctly.

**I have also followed all similar-ish issues on stack overflow to no avail.**

I'm just lost and beyond frustrated at this point, could anyone point me in the right direction?
Any help would be more than appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Self solved,

I removed all instances of setting JAVA_HOME in my fish and bash config files, 
I `unset JAVA_OPTS` (bash) and `set -eU JAVA_OPTS` (fish) 
I switched to java-17-openjdk 
I rebooted.

Then it worked perfectly!